# Subset a list with grepl R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, grepl

I'm trying to subset a list which contains dataframes:

```
Folkersen_IL6.txt
Folkersen_IL16.txt
Folkersen_IL1.txt
Height.txt
Met_Ile.out.txt 
etc
```

I've tried this with the following code:

```
protein <- list.txt[grepl('Folkersen', list.txt)]
```

This line only returns me a list of 1 (containing Folkersen_IL16.txt). How can I get a subset containing all 3 desired dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grepping the names of the list:

```
protein <- list.txt[grepl('Folkersen', names(list.txt))]
```

If the names of your list are *not* currently the data frame names, then just alter your script to populate your list using the data frame names as you add each element.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `startsWith`

```
protein <- list.txt[startsWith(names(list.txt), 'Folkersen')]
```